# Variable content outside of a method

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm working on getting jsonp information back from a page and I want to run various functions on that information. The information comes back fine but I can't seem to find a way to make it accessible outside of the function. I know it's something to do with closure and function scope but I can't figure out how to make it work, any ideas?

I can achieve what I'm trying to do in the rest of the script by making multiple calls to the json file but I assume it's better to just query the json once and pop it into a variable and try work off that? I'm relatively new to this set up so any suggestions appreciated.

Effectively from the code below I want to be able to get the allMatches variable accessible outside of the getData method after it runs.

Thanks for your time, all help greatly appreciated.

```
var AppInfo = {
    getData :  function(){

                var responseJsonVar;
                var callbackName, script, newInfo, mydata,allMatches;
                // Get a random name for the callback
                callbackName = "checkGames" + new Date().getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

                // create the jsonP script call on the page
                script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = "http://www.hookhockey.com/index.php/temp-gillian/?callback=" + callbackName;
                document.documentElement.appendChild(script);

                // call the json
                window[callbackName] = function(data) {

                    responseJsonVar = data; // this is the info back from the json file

                    //the filtered data source from json
                    var allMatches = responseJsonVar["matches"];

                    console.dir('allMatches inside the function: ' + allMatches); //this comes back fine



                        // Remove our callback ('delete' with 'window properties fails on some versions of IE, so we fall back to setting the property to 'undefined' if that happens)
                        try {
                            delete window[callbackName];
                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            window[callbackName] = undefined;
                        }

         //I've tried putting a return value (return allMatches) in here and then calling window[callbackName]() outside of the function but I get undefined for matches

                }; // end  window[callbackName] function

    //this is what I think I should be doing to get the info out on its own
    console.dir('allMatches OUTSIDE the function: ' + allMatches); //this doesn't come back 'allMatches is not defined'


    } //end getdata method

} //end AppInfo


AppInfo.getData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a property on your `AppInfo` object called `allMatches` and set that property when the data comes back from the jsonp call:

```
var AppInfo = {
  allMatches: null, // NEW PROPERTY TO HOLD RETURNED DATA
  confirmDataAvailableOutsideFunction: function () { // NEW FUNCTION TO VERIFY DATA AVAILABLE OUTSIDE getData()
    console.dir('AppInfo.allMatches OUTSIDE the function AFTER jsonp call executes: ' + AppInfo.allMatches); //this doesn't come back 'allMatches is not defined'
  },
  getData: function () {

    var responseJsonVar;
    var callbackName, script, newInfo, mydata, allMatches;
    // Get a random name for the callback
    callbackName = "checkGames" + new Date().getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

    // create the jsonP script call on the page
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://www.hookhockey.com/index.php/temp-gillian/?callback=" + callbackName;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);

    // call the json
    window[callbackName] = function (data) {

      responseJsonVar = data; // this is the info back from the json file

      //the filtered data source from json
      AppInfo.allMatches = responseJsonVar["matches"]; // store data in allMatches property

      console.dir('allMatches inside the function: ' + AppInfo.allMatches); //this comes back fine
      AppInfo.confirmDataAvailableOutsideFunction(); // call test method to verify allMatches property is set

      // Remove our callback ('delete' with 'window properties fails on some versions of IE, so we fall back to setting the property to 'undefined' if that happens)
      try {
        delete window[callbackName];
      }
      catch (e) {
        window[callbackName] = undefined;
      }

      //I've tried putting a return value (return allMatches) in here and then calling window[callbackName]() outside of the function but I get undefined for matches

    }; // end  window[callbackName] function

    //this is what I think I should be doing to get the info out on its own
    console.dir('AppInfo.allMatches OUTSIDE the function BEFORE jsonp call executes: ' + AppInfo.allMatches); //this doesn't come back 'allMatches is not defined'


  } //end getdata method

}; //end AppInfo

AppInfo.getData();
```

Note that I modified the text of your second `console.dir` to indicate that it's running *before* the jsonp call returns, and therefore the `allMatches` property is still `null` at that point.

That's why, after implementing @peter-b's suggestion to use `window.allMatches` instead of local variable `allMatches`, `window.allMatches` OUTSIDE the function was `undefined`--you were checking it before it was set.

@peter-b's solution would work fine, provided that you didn't try to access `window.allMatches` before it was set. So if you want the data stored in a global variable, you can use his method; if you'd rather have it stored on your AppInfo object, you can use mine.

Alternatively, you can wrap everything in an immediate function that has `allMatches` as a local variable:

```
(function () {
  var allMatches = null;

  var AppInfo = {
    getData: function (dataReadyCallback) {

      /* ... */
      allMatches = responseJsonVar["matches"];
      dataReadyCallback();
      /* ... */

    }
  };

  AppInfo.getData(allMatchesReady);

  function allMatchesReady() {
    console.dir('allMatches OUTSIDE the function AFTER jsonp call executes: ' + allMatches);
  }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to get what you want is to assign `allMatches` as a property of the `window`, making it accessible everywhere. Replace

```
var allMatches = responseJsonVar["matches"];
```

with

```
window.allMatches = responseJsonVar["matches"];
```

and then access it later using `window.allMatches`.

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion.. I have replaced as suggested and then changed my console log to console.log('allMatches OUTSIDE the function: ' + window.allMatches); but I'm afraid I get "allMatches OUTSIDE the function: undefined" in the console now.